# What is an Erlang Design pattern that for "Process as Message" work queue?

Tags: design-patterns, erlang, erlang-otp

I'm trying to figure out a design pattern that was mentioned in an erlang talk.
Essentially the speaker mentions using a work queue using a "message as a process" rather then using the job as a process.

The key idea being that by using a "message as a process" you are able to save serialization/deserialization overhead.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a link to the talk?

Comment: I'd like to see the talk as well. There is some context I'd like to have before I feel I can answer correctly.

Comment: 12.00 minute-mark onward http://www.erlang-factory.com/conference/SFBay2010/speakers/jackmoffit

Comment: Ah, that is an important Erlang-idiom, answer below :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let `M` be an Erlang term() which is a *message* we send around in the system. One obvious way to handle `M` is to build a pipeline of processes and queues. `M` is processed by the first worker in the pipeline and then sent on to the next queue. It is then picked up by the next worker process, processed again and put into a queue. And so on until the message has been fully processed.

The perhaps not-so-obvious way is to define a process `P` and then hand `M` to `P`. We will notate it as `P(M)`. Now the message itself is a *process* and not a piece of *data*. `P` will do the same job that the workers did in the queue-solution but it won't have to pay the overhead of sticking the `M` back into queues and pick it off again and so on. When the processing `P(M)` is done, the process will simply end its life. If handed another message `M'` we will simply spawn `P(M')` and let it handle that message concurrently. If we get a set of processes, we will do `[P(M) || M <- Set]` and so on.

If `P` needs to do synchronization or messaging, it can do so without having to "impersonate" the message, since it *is* the message. Contrast with the worker-queue approach where a worker has to take responsibility for a message that comes along it. If `P` has an error, only the message `P(M)` affected by the error will crash. Again, contrast with the worker-queue approach where a crash in the pipeline may affect other messages (mostly if the pipeline is badly designed).

So the trick in conclusion: Turn a message into a process that *becomes* the message.

The idiom is 'One Process per Message' and is quite common in Erlang. The price and overhead of making a new process is low enough that this works. You may want some kind of overload protection should you use the idea however. The reason is that you probably want to put a limit to the amount of concurrent requests so you *control* the load of the system rather than blindly let it destroy your servers. One such implementation is *Jobs*, created by Erlang Solutions, see

https://github.com/esl/jobs

and Ulf Wiger is presenting it at:

http://www.erlang-factory.com/conference/ErlangFactoryLiteLA/speakers/UlfWiger

As Ulf hints in the talk, we will usually do some preprocessing outside `P` to parse the message and internalize it to the Erlang system. But as soon as possible we will make the message `M` into a *job* by wrapping it in a process (`P(M)`). Thus we get the benefits of the Erlang Scheduler right away.

There is another important ramification of this choice: If processing takes a long time for a message, then the preemptive scheduler of Erlang will ensure that messages with less processing needs still get handled quickly. If you have a limited amount of worker queues, you may end up with many of them being clogged, hampering the throughput of the system.